# ethtool "Operation not supported"

Tags: centos, linux-networking, centos7

I cant change *any* adapter settings with ethtool.

```
ethtool -s eno1 speed 1000 duplex full autoneg on
Cannot set net settings: Operation not supported
```

This same message appears with any combination of the above settings.

I've also tried editing `/etc/sysconfig/network-scipts/ifcfg-eno1` by adding the line:

```
ETHTOOL_OPTS="speed 1000 duplex full autoneg on"
```

But running `ethtool eno1` shows this after a reboot:

[image]

I really need to get this link up. It's a new box with CentOS7 I'm trying to get off the ground.

Comment: Is the interface "_up_"? What is the NIC? It's feasable that it doesn't support what you're trying to do (hence "_Operation not supported_")... what's wrong with letting autonegotiation do its thing?

Comment: The switch is supposedly alive and kicking. The board is **SuperMicro X11DPL**. I'd love to autoneg but I cant turn it on!

Comment: It's saying no link detected. Check the cable and switch port.